# Create a variable/object/resource that is accessible through entire application in ZF2

Tags: frameworks, zend-framework2

To be specific, I need to create an array variable that will be used for caching data, but I don't want to use ZF2 Cache Adapter.

I've tried to create a invokable class that would be used to instantiate object of my class that contains methods for setting and getting values from array that is also defined as a property of that class. As far as I understand, service manager treats all services as shared by default, which is supposed to create only one instance off my class when I get the service by service manager method get for the first time. But this doesn't work, if I get that service in different actions in my Controller class, which is what I need to do. So, how am I supposed to achieve this effect? Create an object that is available application-wide?

Comment: When you say "application-wide" do you mean across different page requests? And why don't you want to use the cache adapter?

Comment: Because memcache is not enabled on server and memory cache adapter depends on php script that is being executed, and loading data in files is not an option. I want to use cache for translations, which I load from database. I haven't been able to figure out how to load translations from my database to zf2 translator service.

Comment: I am working with an old and very large database, and changing and creating new tables for this purpose is not an option. So, I thought I could create an array that will be used for caching translations so that the application doesn't always connects to database and loads translations instead of loading them from cache array. So yes, by "application-wide" I mean across different page requests - inside different controller actions.

Comment: Nothing is shared between requests out-of-the-box in PHP, so you have to use some sort of cache for your class, whether it's Memcache, Redis, APC or file system.

Answer (score 0):

I had this kind of problem with managing a cart.

My cart is modeled by a CartManager, which is a unique instance for a user (session) and until paiement (cart is persisted in database).

I register my CartManager as a Service to build the first instance, this instance is built during an event handler attached on `MvcEvent::EVENT_ROUTE`, once built I override the CartManager service with my Instance, this way wherever I call the service, my first instance is served.

Then I persist (session or database) my Instance in an other event handler attached on `MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH`.

All the event handlers are attached in Module::onBoostrap()